# EC2インスタンス内にgit cloneしたリポジトリから、GitHubに対しpushもpullもできなくなった

Tags: git, github, amazon-ec2

Amazon EC2インスタンス内にgithub経由で `git clone` したリポジトリから、pushもpullもできなくなってしまいました。

初学者のため、至らない点があるかもしれないですが、2日ほど調べてトライアンドエラーをしましたが、解決しなく、ご教授頂けると幸いです。宜しくお願いいたします。

#### 環境

- macbook pro
- terminal
- Amazon EC2 インスタンス

#### できていること

- ssh keyのgithubへの登録
- `ssh git@github.com` でssh接続をすると、下記の表示が出て接続が成功する

  ```
  Hi [username]! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
  provide shell access.Connection to github.com closed.
  ```
- ssh接続をするように設定されています。 `git remote -v` で確認すると下記の表示。

  ```
  origin  ssh://[username]@github.com/[organization]/[repo].git (fetch)
  origin  ssh://[username]@github.com/[organization]/[repo].git (push)
  ```

#### 出来ていないこと(困ってること)

- `git push origin`, `sudo git push origin`, `git push git@github.com:[organization]/[repo].git` でも全て下記が返ってくる

  ```
  Permission denied (publickey).
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
  ```

Comment: このエラーが出たときのトラブルシューティングが help.github.com にありました（[こちら](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/)）。`ssh -vT git@github.com` で確認しても解決しませんでしょうか？　また、鍵ペアが正しいものか確認なさいましたか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
`ssh -vT git@github.com` を確認しても特にssh接続でエラーがでているわけではありませんでした。キーペア自体も正しく、ssh接続は確立されているようなのです。。

Comment: 解決しました。sudo でgitコマンドを叩いており、そのことで、githubに登録したユーザーとssh実行ユーザーが異なっていることが原因でした。
`ssh -T git@github.com`実行時にはsudoでなかったため、 githubに登録したユーザーと同ユーザーでアクセスしに行っており、通っていたようです。
sudoでコマンドを実行すると、ユーザーが切り替わるという基本的な部分の理解が欠落していたことが原因でした。お騒がせいたしました。そして回答をお寄せ頂き、大変たすかりました。
ありがとうございました。またお伺いすることがあると思いますが、よろしくおねがいいたします。

Answer (score 1):

sudo でgitコマンドを叩いており、そのことで、githubに登録したユーザーとssh実行ユーザーが異なっていることが原因でした。

`ssh -T git@github.com`実行時にはsudoでなかったため、 githubに登録したユーザーと同ユーザーでアクセスしに行っており、通っていたようです。sudoでコマンドを実行するとユーザーが切り替わるという基本的な部分の理解が欠落していたことが原因でした。

<sub>-- [質問者さん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/24444/kyosu-ke)の[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/36428/ec2%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E5%86%85%E3%81%ABgit-clone%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%83%AA%E3%83%9D%E3%82%B8%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89-github%E3%81%AB%E5%AF%BE%E3%81%97push%E3%82%82pull%E3%82%82%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F#comment36411_36428)より</sub>

Answer (score 0):

git のリモートとして設定されている URLの書式が間違っているように見受けられます。

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:[organization]/[repo].git
```

として、 git pull などを行うとどうなりますでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
上記コマンドを実行し、
`git remote -v`で確認すると、下記のように設定ができました。

origin git@github.com:[organization]/[repo].git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:[organization]/[repo].git (push)

のち、`git push` を行いましたが、引き続き
下記が出てまいります。。

Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights

Comment: @Kyosu-ke なるほど、、だとすると、1.  organization か repo のスペルミスもしくは、 2. ssh で公開鍵を紐づけたアカウントは 該当レポジトリに対するアクセス権限がない ぐらいしか思いつかない状態ですね。。

Comment: ありがとうございます。上記2つを手がかりに調べてみます。根本的な部分ですが抜けている可能性があるので…！